# How to call a method declared in an applet from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I am trying to make a basic [Java applet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) to open a file on the client's computer for them. I would like to call the openFile function in the Java applet below via JavaScript.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Test extends JApplet {
    public void openFile(String filePath) {
        File f = new File(filePath);

        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In between the body tags of my webpage I have the following:

```html
<applet code="Test.class" height="0" width="0"></applet>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.applets[0].openFile("C:\\test.log");
</script>
```

When I load the page I get the error:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'openFile'

What do I need to do to fix this error and get the applet working?

Comment: The applet will be a component in a version control system. A separate web service copies the file to the clients computer when they "check-out" code but I want to automatically open it in their default text editor at the same time. If you can think of an easier way to open the text file I'm all ears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
<script src=
  "http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

<script>
    <!-- The applet id can be used to get a reference to
    the applet object -->
    var attributes = { id:'mathApplet',
        code:'jstojava.MathApplet',  width:1, height:1};
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'math-applet.jnlp'};
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

Reference: *[Invoking Applet Methods From JavaScript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)*

JavaScript is allowed to directly call the applet’s public methods or public variables. JavaScript considers the embedded applet as an object. By providing the applet with an ID, JavaScript can access it with:

```
    document.Applet_ID.Applet_Method()
```

And you can use this,

#### File *MyApplet.html*

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="Javascript">
        function accessAppletMethod()
        {
            document.getElementById("AppletABC").appendText("Applet Method");
        }
    </script>

    <title>Testing</title>
</head>

<body onload="accessAppletMethod()">

    <h1>Javascript acess Applet method</h1>

    <applet width=300 height=100 id="AppletABC"
        code="JavaScriptToJava.class">
    </applet>
</body>

</html>
```

#### File *JavaScriptToJava.java*

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.TextArea;

public class JavaScriptToJava extends Applet{

    TextArea textBox;

    public void init(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        textBox = new TextArea(5, 40);
        add(textBox);
    }

    public void appendText(String text){
        textBox.append(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: And since when can you do `document.Applet_ID`?

Comment: @Ian, I believe, now you would be happy with my update ?? Or still I need more improvement ??

Comment: @Daniel are you sure, you are getting that error ?? Your `.class` file in right place ?? please check

Comment: You can't use `document.AppletABC`, I'm not sure where you got that from. You can do that when the `name` of the element is set though, not with `id`s. `document.getElementById("AppletABC")` is how you should do it. Also, I don't think you can put `<script>` next to the `<head>` element...you have to put it inside of `<head>` or `<body>`.

Comment: I think the issue was I did not have an init function so the applet was not properly starting. Thanks.

Comment: @Ian: Actually, you can use the ID; it references the `applet` tag.